# Problem loading specific WMS with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, getmap

I try to add this WMS in a Leaflet map by using the L.tileLayer.wms.

https://glfc72.cfsnet.nfis.org/mapserver/cgi-bin/mapserver.cgi?map=/data/htdocs/glfc.cfsnet.nfis.org/mapserver/fire/public_html/ews_cmc_dev.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-20037507.842788246,-30240971.458386172,20037507.842788246,30240971.458386205&WIDTH=579&HEIGHT=874&LAYERS=fwi&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=XML&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFEFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

And I get a 302 found error in Firebug. I am able to add the wms to ArcGIS Online without any problem but I would like to make it work in Leaflet because I do need a more personalized site. I am just starting with Leaflet so any kind of guideline about this would be very welcomed.

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how you added the layer?

Comment: please only use tags that are relevant to your actual question

Answer (score 4):

I have no problems loading that WMS service.

```
var wms = L.tileLayer.wms('https://glfc72.cfsnet.nfis.org/mapserver/cgi-bin/mapserver.cgi?', {
  map: '/data/htdocs/glfc.cfsnet.nfis.org/mapserver/fire/public_html/ews_cmc_dev.map',
  layers: 'fwi',
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.8
}).addTo(map);
```